# how to change root permission by text console

Tags: permissions, root

I have edited and restarted the permission for both root and others for a folder 'usr' and restarted the system now ican only load the text console how to change the permission of that folder using teaxt console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo chmod 755 /usr` should do the trick